# display fps is 0 when nothing is happening

Tags: python, pygame, frame-rate

I am making a rudimentary platformer, and while debugging the game I noticed a problem, whenever I run the game, nothing happens (my fps is 0) until I press a key, move my mouse, or cause any type of event. And this isn't just my fps tanking, if I do something my fps usually shoots to 100 or 200.

I have honestly no idea what is going on because I have never encountered this problem ever. I've tried changing the driver, changing display tags, messing with the clock, checked the docs and tried to find a question like this, but to no avail.

here is my main:

```py
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        import pygame
        from pygame.math import Vector2
        import os
        from Database.Player import Player
        import platform
        pygame.init()

        # file path
        file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

        # changing driver
        if platform.system() == "Windows":
            os.environ["SDL_VIDEODRIVER"] = "directx"

        # screen vars
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800), pygame.RESIZABLE)
        screen_info = pygame.display.Info()
        screen_size = Vector2(screen_info.current_w, screen_info.current_h)
        game_resolution = Vector2(800, 800)
        game_offset = Vector2(screen_size / 2 - game_resolution / 2)

        # class initializations
        player = Player((400, 0), file_path)

        # screen caption
        pygame.display.set_caption(f"reeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee")

        # clock
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        leave = False
        while not leave:
            pygame.display.set_caption(str(clock.get_fps()))

            # delta time
            delta_time = clock.get_time() / 1000

            # key presses
            key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            # event
            event = pygame.event.wait()
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT or key[pygame.K_DELETE]:
                leave = True

            elif event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
                game_offset = Vector2(Vector2(event.size) / 2 - game_resolution / 2)
                screen = pygame.display.set_mode(event.size, pygame.RESIZABLE)

            # update
            player.update(key, delta_time)
            player.draw(screen, game_offset)
            pygame.display.flip()
            screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
            clock.tick(1000)

        pygame.display.quit()
        return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

and here is the player class

```py
import pygame
from pygame.math import Vector2


class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, start_pos, file_path):
        # visual
        self.image = pygame.Surface((20, 20))


        # positional
        self.pos = start_pos
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(start_pos, self.image.get_size())
        self.speed = Vector2(0)
        self.deceleration = 0.1
        self.acceleration = Vector2(4000, 0)
        self.gravity = Vector2(0, 800)
        self.max_speed = Vector2(1000, 1000)
        self.jump_speed = Vector2(0, 500)

        # properties
        self.jump = True

    def draw(self, surface, game_offset):
        surface.blit(self.image, self.pos + game_offset)

    def update(self, key, delta_time):

        if key[pygame.K_a]:
            self.speed.x -= self.acceleration.x * delta_time

        if key[pygame.K_d]:
            self.speed.x += self.acceleration.x * delta_time

        if key[pygame.K_w] or key[pygame.K_SPACE] and self.jump:
            self.speed.y -= self.jump_speed.y

        self.speed.y += self.gravity.y * delta_time

        self.speed.x = max(-self.max_speed.x, min(self.speed.x, self.max_speed.x))
        self.speed.y = max(-self.max_speed.y, min(self.speed.y, self.max_speed.y))

        self.pos += self.speed * delta_time
```

Am I missing something obvious here? Is my problem even reproducible on other pc's??? I honestly have no idea. I would be grateful for any advice anyone could give. And thank you for spending the time to read my code and answer if you do.

Comment: it stops because you use `pygame.event.wait()` which block code till you move mouse or press key. Use standard loop `for event in pygame.event.get():`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call to `pygame.event.wait()` will actually *wait* for an event. What you need to do (to keep things running) is to call `pygame.event.get()`.

However, `get()` returns a *list* of events that have occurred since you last called it, so the proper way of doing it is something like:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT or key[pygame.K_DELETE]:
        leave = True
        break # No need to carry on if you're finishing up.

    if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
        game_offset = Vector2(Vector2(event.size) / 2 - game_resolution / 2)
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode(event.size, pygame.RESIZABLE)
    # elif other events.

# Update stuff regardless of events.

player.update(key, delta_time)
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
player.draw(screen, game_offset)
pygame.display.flip()
clock.tick(1000)
```

Comment: Thank you it works, i had read somewhere that `pygame.event.wait()` was faster but i had no idea it had this effect

Comment: @loukylor, it *may* be faster since it only gives you the next event, not an entire list. It's downside (waiting, which causes your main loop to pause until an event shows up) far outweighs that benefit in this case :-)

Comment: I took the liberty to move the drawing related code out of the event handling `for` loop. Since multiple events can happen per frame, you also don't want to call `clock.tick()` once per events.